# How Spark MLlib deal with Java program?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I was wondering how Spark deal with Java program calling some machine learing algorithm provided by MLlib. Do I need to download [Spark Project ML Library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.10)? What's more, where is the source code of MLlib for Java API ? I can't find it in it's [repository](https://github.com/apache/spark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark MLlib is written in Scala, you could directly use it.
In repository it's [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib).

You could also check some examples [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-guide.html)

Comment: So, what MLlib  do for  a Java or  Python API? Does  it  implement those  machine learning  algorithms in  Java  or  Python? Or  it  only call corresponding scala  implementation for a Java or  Python API?

Comment: For Java program, it calls directly scala implementation. For Python Spark have Pyspark which implements also mllib, please check it out [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/python/pyspark/mllib)

Comment: But what for algorithms in module ml (not MLlib)? Can't find detail of implementation.

Comment: The same as ml, Java API uses Scala implementation, see [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml), and pyspark has its own implementation, see [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/python/pyspark/ml)

Comment: Yes, I've found it.  But not  like algorithms in module mllib, algorithms in module ml extends some classes like JavaEstimator and there  is  not any code I can  find  used  to train it. Can you tell me the   mechanism of  module ml?  Thank you.

Comment: ml package is a `DataFrame` based machine learning package, while mllib package is `RDD` based. ml helps users create and tune practical machine learning pipelines. so what's important in ml is the pipeline mechanism. For details, you could check the [ml documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html), it explains how pipeline works in ml, you could learn a lot from it.